# Как правильно в Modx Revolution фильтровать по TV параметрам?

Tags: modx, revo

Всем привет, подскажите как правильно в **Modx Revolution** фильтровать по **TV параметрам**? мне нужно в зависимости от id пользователя показывать/скрывать контент. Вывожу контент при помощи getresources:

```
[[!getResources?
&showHidden=`1`
&tpl=`order`
&limit=`10`
&includeContent=`1`
&includeTVs=`1`
&resources=`6,7,8,9`
&debug=`1`
&tvPrefix=``
&tvFilters=`{"tv.user_id":[[!+modx.user.id]]}`
&processTVs=`1`]]
```

не получается на данный момент ничего( Подскажите в чем проблема? То ли в синтаксе то ли в логике 
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1):

насколько я помню в **getResources** с фильтрами работает по tv не в формате **json**, надо писать так примерно `&tvFilters='myTvCountry==России'` притом что имя tv к примеру: `myTvCountry` 
P.S. да и кавычки я поставил не правильные, поставь сам правильно

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо, отвечу на вопрос сам - писать нужно вот так

```
&tvFilters=`user_id==[[!+modx.user.id]]`
```